# Does tearing down and restarting an AppDomain refresh the Large Object Heap

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, appdomain

Using .net 2.0, if we allocate large objects so that they go in the Large Object Heap (LOH), and gradually fragment the LOH, does tearing down the Domain and restarting it effectively give you a new LOH to work with?

I suspect the memory at that level is managed at a process level, and restarting the whole process is the only way to get an unfragmented heap in .net 2.0, but I couldn't find a clear answer online...

Comment: No, the LOH is shared between all AppDomains.  If fragmentation is getting a problem then switching to 64-bit code is the obvious and simple solution.  Avoid getting stuck on 9 year old versions of free software.

Comment: Thanks, as you've been on the scene for a while I'm sure you know it's not always our choice!

Comment: I've been around long enough to know that getting stuck in a technological dead-end is fatal to a programmer's career.  [Of course it is your choice](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/).